# Understanding Selenium's WebDriverException, "unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've created a try/except for NoSuchElementException, so I don't understand why it's doing this.

```
try:
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, some_element).click() 
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    #not found code here
```

I'm getting a `WebDriverException`, with the message `Unable to locate element`.

Why isn't it throwing NoSuchElementException?

Comment: Can't reproduce. You are obviously have more code there, `break` is not valid here, something else is what throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:
1. Invalid element(Make sure that you are using right element in xpath)

(or)
2. Your script is not waiting until element is present on screen. Use wait command before     self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, some_element).click()

Comment: This is not what the OP asked.